# gvpack (graphviz) not preserving labels of the individual digraphs

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato

There are four dot files (cluster_0, cluster_1, cluster_2, cluster_3) which need to be merged into a single dot file.

The code of the individual dot files is as follows.

```
digraph cluster_0{
sortv=1;
penwidth=0;pencolor=transparent;
label="1A";
rankdir=LR;
 node [fontname = "times-roman-bold",fontsize=12];
        edge [fontname = "times-roman-bold",fontsize=12,arrowsize=0.75];
    1 [label="1:A"];
    2 [label="2:C"];
    3 [label="3:G"];
    3 -> 1
    1 -> 2
    3 -> 2
    2 -> 3
}
digraph cluster_1 {
sortv=2;
penwidth=0;pencolor=transparent;
 label="1B";
 node [fontname = "times-roman-bold",fontsize=12];
        edge [fontname = "times-roman-bold",fontsize=12,arrowsize=0.75];
    rankdir=LR;
    11 [label="1:A"];
    12 [label="2:C"];
    13 [label="3:G"];
    14 [label="4:T"];
    14 -> 11
    11 -> 12
    12 -> 13
    12 -> 14 
    13 -> 14
}
digraph cluster_2 {
    rankdir=LR;
  sortv=3;
penwidth=0;pencolor=transparent;
  label="1C";
 node [fontname = "times-roman-bold",fontsize=12];
        edge [fontname = "times-roman-bold",fontsize=12,arrowsize=0.75];
    21 [label="1:A"];
    22 [label="2:C"];
    23 [label="3:G"];
    24 [label="4:T"];
    25 [label="5:A"];
    24 -> 21
    21 -> 22
    21 -> 25
    25 -> 22
    22 -> 23
    23 -> 24
}
digraph cluster_3{
        sortv=4;
penwidth=0;pencolor=transparent;
        label="1D"
 node [fontname = "times-roman-bold",fontsize=12];
        edge [fontname = "times-roman-bold",fontsize=12,arrowsize=0.75];
    rankdir=LR;
    31 [label="1:A"];
    32 [label="2:C"];
    33 [label="3:G"];
    31:c -> 31:w
    32 -> 31 [dir=both,len=1.25];
    33 -> 31 [dir=both,];
    32 -> 32
    33 -> 32 [dir=both,];
    33 -> 33
}
```

To generate a merged single dot file ...I ran the following command.

```
neato -Gstart=5 cluster_0.dot cluster_1.dot cluster_2.dot cluster_3.dot | gvpack -array_u4 | neato -n2 -s -Teps -o merge.eps
```

merge.eps came perfectly well but the labels of the individual graphs went missing. How can we preserve the labels of the individual graphs in the output merge file ? Can anyone help to fix this ?

Here I am attaching the single individual file where the label is shown
I compiled the individual file with the following command.

```
neato -Gstart=5 cluster_0.dot -Teps -o cluster_0.eps
```

Also I am attaching the merge output file which removed the labels of the graphs.

[image]

Comment: From the `man gcoack` file: _An input graph should not have a label, since this will be used in its layout. Since gvpack ignores root graph labels, resulting layout may contain some extra space._ This is considered a bug, but it's there...

Comment: Thank you @vaettchen for responding :) So there is no way to get label using gvpack ?

Comment: I don't know `gvpack` well enough to confirm that with sufficient authority, but that seems to be the case. Pre-processing the individual files with `awk` or `m4` and combining them into one `dot` file is not an option?

Comment: @vaettchen Thanks :) I will try that !

Comment: You can get some inspiration from [here](https://github.com/vaettchen/m4gv); or give me an hour or two, I'll come up with something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer but rather sharing experiences: As it turns out while experimenting with various options, it seems to be the `neato` engine that supresses the labels. If you use `dot`, you may not get the exact layout you want but you get the labels:

```
dot -Gstart=5 cluster_0.dot cluster_1.dot cluster_2.dot cluster_3.dot | gvpack -array_u4 | dot -n2 -s -T jpg -o merge.jpg
```

gives you

[image]

My personal preference would by to have one master file `so.m4`

```
digraph so 
{
    define(`digraph',`subgraph')
    rankdir=LR;
    include(cluster_0.dot)
    include(cluster_1.dot)
    include(cluster_2.dot)
    include(cluster_3.dot)
}
```

that I process with

```
m4 so.m4 > so.dot
```

In the resulting `so.dot` file, I have all clusters combined, and I can go to the next step (here producing a JPG) with a simple

```
dot -T png -o so.png so.dot
```

The advantage of that is that you can use the master file for "global options". I think it is easier to maintain and less unwieldy than the command with all the pipes and options. But that's a matter of taste.

With the option `rankdir=LR;` this version is produced:

[image]

Have fun - happy to do more but I'd need to know more about your project.

Comment: This is interesting. But the point I want to share is neato engine does not supress the labels of the root graph when used in the individual file. You can try the command I shared in the original post neato -Gstart=5 <dotfile>.  While combining gvpack is the one which is creating trouble.For our project we should have the neato engine look for the output graphs :) Just like the one I shared in the original post.

Comment: Is there a way to include layout option for the individual dot file using m4 ?

Comment: What I discovered is that `neato` preserves the labels only on the graph level, not for subgraphs. That's why your compilation with `cluster_0` only works but the packed version, be it with `gvpack` or with `m4', won't.

Comment: got it ! :) the combined versions ignores labels of the individual files. Thanks a lot @vaettchen. finally I got the desired output. I introduced individual image as a node in a new dot file and added invisible edges. It worked :)

Comment: Would be nice if you could upvote my answer, even if it not a solution. I enjoy the effort but a bit of reward is always nice...

Comment: my current reputation is actually not enough to recognize your efforts :P ..But yes ..truly with your insights it got completed :)

Comment: where can I find document about `gvpack` and `m4`?